# ASP.NET MVC Angular on IIS - MIME types configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to deploy my mvc angular application on IIS, everything has been working fine so far. However, now I need to serve some static files with custom extensions (e.g. ***.dma***). For that I have added the appropriate MIME type configuration for my site, and yet it does not seem to work.

The binaries general structure is as such:

```
.
+-- AngularApp
|   +-- dist
    |   +-- assets
        |   +-- specialfile.dma
        |   +-- ...
        +-- index.html
+-- wwwroot
|   +-- icon.svg
+-- appsettings.json
+-- web.config
+-- *.dll
```

My web.config looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mywebapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".dma" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I try to get a file with the extension ***.dma*** from the assets folder, it is not found.
I have already checked that any other file (e.g, a png image) can be retrieved from that same folder, so the routes are fine.

I also deployed my angular application independent from the MVC app, and it turns out I can get the file.

What am I missing here?

Is there any other configuration I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time troubleshooting, I finally figured out what was going on.

It turns out there was a configuration in the code which changed the root path for angular files.

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
     configuration.RootPath = "AngularApp/dist";
});
```

And it seems that IIS was just ignoring any general configuration for this folder.

I had to create a virtual directory for the assets folder, and add the MIME types configuration inside a new location tag.

So, my web.config now looks like this.

```
<configuration>
...
 <location path="assets">
   <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".dma" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
       </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that anything in the "system.webServer" elements needs to be configured in IIS once you deploy the site.  the IIS app config overrides the web.config unless you amend the IIS app config.

[image]

Comment: I was also suspecting that the web.config configuration was getting overwritten by the IIS app config. However, even if I configure the server to map this extension, I am still getting 404 errors. As I said, this does not happen when I just simply deploy the angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods for troubleshooting:

1.Can you request your .dmafile directly from browser and see what the resonse header you get?

2.Enable [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) and look for GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS section in Comple Request Trace tab.